# How do I loop a random audio player when the audio has finished playing?

Tags: javascript, audio

I've been trying to figure out a way to make one song transition to the next, how would I go about this?

I haven't tried much. I'm relatively inexperienced in Javascript so my attempts have generally been futile.

```
var numberOfSongs = 4
var sound = new Array(numberOfSongs+1)
sound[0]= "skytop.mp3"
sound[1]= "ac.mp3"
sound[2]= "forgotten.mp3"
sound[3]= "miserable.mp3"


function randomNumber(){
var randomLooper = -1
while (randomLooper < 0 || randomLooper > numberOfSongs || isNaN(randomLooper)){ randomLooper = parseInt(Math.random()*(numberOfSongs+1))
}
return randomLooper
}
var randomsub = randomNumber()
var soundFile = sound[randomsub]
document.write ('<EMBED src= "' + soundFile + '" hidden=true type="audio/mpeg" autostart=true loop=true>')
```

This is what I'm working with, any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say transition, do you just mean start the list over or what do you mean by transition?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification, I mean having another song selected randomly and played without having to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer (which would take a while!), but it might help you get started. Take a look at these APIs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement

The way you play a clip is like this:

```
var audio = new Audio('url/to/my/audio.mp3');
audio.play();
```

That's gets the audio playing. But since you want to know when the music stops, in order to play the next clip, before you start playing, add an event listener:

```
audio.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
  // Your code to start playing the next clip goes here.
});
```

You can get much fancier, of course. There's enough audio processing capability available that you could crossfade your selections, not just play them sequentially.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help. I was mainly looking for a way to loop back in order to select another random song, but this is equally useful!